# Fix code style rules from the command line for dotnet core

Tags: .net-core, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Is there a command line tool I can invoke that will apply the suggested fix from code style rules? I assume it is Roslyn that generates them, but I could be wrong.

For instance I might have a line of c# code

`new MyNamespace.UI.Grid()`

which generates a "[IDE0001 - Simplify name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0001)" suggestion.

Clearly in the IDE (visual studio for instance) I can choose to accept this and it will remove any unnecessary namespace qualifications.

Is there a tool similar to [dotnet format](https://github.com/dotnet/format) that will allow me to apply all the IDE0001 simplifications to a project from the command line?

Comment: Have you tried using [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CodeStyle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CodeStyle/) with `dotnet-format`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Roslynator.DotNet.Cli` global tool to analyse /fix. It can be [installed](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Roslynator.DotNet.Cli) as:

```
dotnet tool install --global Roslynator.DotNet.Cli --version 0.2.0
```

Define the rules in the file Yourules.ruleset and reference it in your project.

Example:

```
roslynator fix <PROJECT|SOLUTION>  -a  <PATH>
```

`<PATH>` Define one or more paths to an analyzer assembly or a directory that should be searched recursively for analyzer assemblies.

for VS 2019 community, the default location is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\ManagedLanguages
```

Also there is  [console tool](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Roslynator.CommandLine)  working in windows

How to use: [read](https://github.com/JosefPihrt/Roslynator/blob/master/docs/cli/README.md)